# React Native bridge (interaction from react to iOS)

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I'm currently learning `React Native` and I've created a small app where I can send events from my `Objective-C` code to the `React` side of things.

I'm struggling to understand how to asynchronously send events from React to a listener on the `Objective`C side.
I feel I've probably misunderstood a critical part about the Bridging as I'm struggling to search for the correct thing (if it even exists).  Could someone please pointe in the right direction or if this is even feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the answer.  I was searching for the wrong thing (newbie mistake).  Here is a link that helped me: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html